# How to change value of a variable of a python file from another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I have two python file. I want to change variable value by calling the module.

test.py

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Master(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.initialize()


    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.my_clock = StringVar(self)
        self.my_clock.set("12:05")

        clock =Label(self,textvariable = self.my_clock,height=1,\
                     width=5,fg="black",bg="white",font=("Sans", 32,"bold"))

        clock.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='SW')




window = Master(None)
window.configure(background="white")
window.mainloop()
```

test1.py

```
import test
test.window.my_clock.set("13:05")
```

I could not change the value of my_clock variable from test1.py file.How could I change the value of my_clock variable from test1.py file.

Comment: Why do you pass a `parent` argument to your class? What do you think you can pass here? A `Tk` instance does not have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
import test
test.Master(None).my_clock.set("13:05")
```

You do the following:

- Import test
- Instanciate a new instance of the class `Master` (<=> a new object)
- Set a new value for the property `my_clock` of your new object
- Then this new object "disappear", as it was not stored into a variable.

Two possibilities here:

**Instanciate your object in your test.py**

test.py

```
class Master(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        (...)

window = Master()
(...)
```

test2.py

```
import test
test.window.my_clock.set("13:05")
```

**Or use a class variable**

test.py

```
class Master(Tk):
    my_clock = StringVar()
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        (...)
```

test2.py

```
import test
test.Master.my_clock.set("13:05")
```

Comment: Method1 shows the window with previous value. value not updated . and second method shows an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'

Comment: Those are only explanations about why your code could not work, and ideas to solve your problem, not a fully functionnal solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program `test1` to show the window, then it needs to call `window.mainloop()`.

```
import test
window = test.Master(None)
window.my_clock.set("13:05")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You only call the mainloop when you run `test.py` directly (when `__name__ == "__main__"`). When you import it you need to run the mainloop again. Change `test1.py` to:

```
import test

m = test.Master(None)
m.my_clock.set("13:05")

m.mainloop()
```